# How to display woocommerce product addons on custom page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

By using woocommerce product addon i created some custom fields on product page.When i use `do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );`
It shows all the custom fields.I have a custom page page i want to show some custom field but not all.

Comment: Which custom field are you talking about ?

Comment: i create many custom fields using woocommerce product addons plugin.i want to display some of them in a particular page.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://s3.postimg.org/w5wsdv1hv/woo.png) ?
Have you added this field from here ?

Comment: Not here,At first i active woocommerce product addons.Then i found a sidebar menu under advance that is Add-ons using that i create custom fields and it's group

Comment: [take a look at here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577307/woocommerce-how-to-display-fields-from-the-product-add-ons-extension). I have not used that so I can't help you.Sorry

Comment: i looked this url.there's not what i want.Thank for your try.

Comment: WC ! What I can tell you is check where data is stored in database and try to fetch them with `wp_query` if you don't find any solution and you are in hurry.