# WooCommerce Product Addons on auction product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, add-on, dokan

I bought a theme using Dokan. We installed addons product with Dokan but the field is not displayed on the auction products that use the WooCommerce simple auctions module how can I activate the add-ons field of the products on the page of an auction product. Knowing that the field is well created on the seller dashboard side and on the product page of the WooCommerce administration?

I found this tread below, but it doesn't work:

[WooCommerce: How to display fields from the "Product Add-ons" extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577307/woocommerce-how-to-display-fields-from-the-product-add-ons-extension)

Comment: we managed to integrate the addons on the auction page but we realized that it does not work as it should. We should display the addons on the checkout page to update the final amount.

We have created a drop-down list of delivery prices but we also want to be able to display it on the price of the product in the dokan auction.

Someone would have any idea ? THANK YOU